# Right Slide In Panel like WunderList App

Tags: android

I would like to see if anyone knows how WunderList did this?  See picture:

[image]

Basically, if you click on any List Item you add, this drawer pops out to show the item details.  In this case I randomly added an item, apparently called "Rgh".  Clicked on it, and it slides out from the right.  You can swipe it and it goes back to whence it came from.

I thought it was a `SliderMenu` library, perhaps one like jfeinstein10's, but Wunderlist already has a slider on the left.  The one on the right (in picture) acts totally different.  Its bigger, instead of pushing content, it just goes over the previous Activity (or Fragment?).  And its not openable from swiping (only closing).  I know with jfeinstien's, you can't do any of that - Right and LEft ahve to be very similar (unless you sublcass it).

I know there was something called the SlidingDrawer, but I hardly see this used anymore, could this be it?  What is the most preferred way to implement this?

Comment: ViewFlipper maybe, no wait,  probably not.  But worth checking out if you haven't before!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LinearLayout plus Animation.  I've done similar in my app.
Not even using Fragments.  Using an Animation class, the code is here:

```
/*
This class is responsible for showing the sliding animation
*/
public class SlideAnim extends Animation {
    int targetWidth;
    View slideView;
    ImageView imageView;
    boolean close;

    public SlideAnim(View _v, boolean _close, int _maxWidth, ImageView imageView) {
        this.slideView = _v;
        this.imageView = imageView;
        targetWidth = _maxWidth;
        close = _close;
    }

    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        int newWidth;
        if (!close) {
            newWidth = (int) (targetWidth * interpolatedTime);
        } else {
            newWidth = (int) (targetWidth * (1 - interpolatedTime));
        }
        slideView.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
        slideView.requestLayout();
        imageView.setImageResource(slideView.getWidth() > 0 ? R.drawable.purple_arrow_right : R.drawable.purple_arrow_left);
    }

    public void initalize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    }

    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is how I am invoking the animation from another Activity:

```
SlideAnim slideAnim = new SlideAnim(trendingListLayout, false, maxListWidth, imageView);
slideAnim.setDuration(500);
slideAnim.reset();
trendingListLayout.clearAnimation();
trendingListLayout.startAnimation(slideAnim);
```

I am animating a LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/top_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.eazyigz.views.EazyigzImageView
        android:id="@+id/whole_screen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/explore_expander"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/eazyigz_bg_primary"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="invisible" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/explore_expander_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/purple_arrow_left" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- List Layout -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/explore_list_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:background="@color/eazyigz_bg_secondary"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="invisible" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:text="@string/top_trending"
                android:textColor="@color/eazyigz_green"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/explore_spinner"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_spinner"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/explore_list"
                style="@style/EazyigzListView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:divider="#0000"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eazyigz_play"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/eazyigz_button"
            android:drawablePadding="0dp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/playing"
            android:textColor="@color/eazyigz_white"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eazyigz_create"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/eazyigz_button"
            android:drawablePadding="0dp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/create"
            android:textColor="@color/eazyigz_white"
            android:textSize="36sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eazyigz_explore"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/eazyigz_button"
            android:drawablePadding="0dp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/explore"
            android:textColor="@color/eazyigz_white"
            android:textSize="36sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eazyigz_listen"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/eazyigz_button"
            android:drawablePadding="0dp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="50dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/stations"
            android:textColor="@color/eazyigz_white"
            android:textSize="36sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>

</merge>
```

The **explore_list_layout** is what gets animated.

See video of what the screen looks like: [Sliding Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HmXra5Q3zM)

Comment: Would it be a Fragment or Activity?  Assuming Fragment if Framelayout?

Comment: Also..  Are you using a Fragment transaction and adding animation this way?

Answer (score 3):

Hello KickingLettuce

Hi Igor

We needed a panel coming from the right, on top of the rest of the application, and we wanted it to be "swipeable" including the basic "nearest-point" opening or closing and acceleration tracking to decide what to do if the swiping was done half-way.

We tried initially with Android's SlidingDrawer but firstly its deprecation and then the ability to swipe just from a knob in the side + its not-so-perfect performance made us to think about doing something else.

We call it SlidingLayer and we are shortly planning to open-source it very soon. We just want to make sure to add a pair of tweaks that give you some flexibility without having to dive deep into unnecessary parts of the code (ie.: adding shadow easily).
In the meantime and if it helps you, we based a huge part of it on the SlidingMenu operation (we love how it works).
It's basically a container (extends from a RelativeLayout that might turn into a ViewGroup - I'd love to debate that - RelativeLayout -> pro: versatile, avoid extra views. con: you might need a different layout). That is being scrolled (with scrollTo) following the moves of your finger -> by overriding and analyzing touch in onInterceptTouchEvent and onTouchEvent. 
It's relatively easy. I'd cheer you to go for it. There are already good tutorials and code examples around this two methods.

Nevertheless and if you prefer to not to get into the burden, I'll let you know whenever we are ready.
I'll make a brief follow up here in case you decide to go for it.

All the best.

Comment: As an addition to this answer, the code for this sliding layer has been open sourced. Check it out in GitHub https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib

Comment: Thank youuuu soo much i was soo close to writing my own library for this